# How can I expand an independant parameter in the function from a single value into a vector?

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, signal-processing, difference

I am trying to determine the stability of the following system:
y(n-2)-4y(n-1)+(λ+6)y(n)-4y(n+1)+y(n+2)=λx(n).
The following is my code:

```
function stable2(k)
k =5;
b = [0 0 k 0 0];
a = [1 -4 k+6 -4 1];
zplane(b,a);
p = roots(a);
pm = roundn(abs(p),-4);
if max(pm)>1 %double-sided
    disp('System is stable');
else
    disp('System is not stable');
end
```

My question is: In my code, I can only enter a single value for λ like 1 or 1.5. How can I input λ as a vector that contains multiple values and thus, so I can prove the stability of the system with different λ simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

```
eigVec = [1, 2, 3];
for i = 1:length(eigVec)
  chckStb(eigVec(i)) % Goes over all eigenvalues
end
```

Organize your stability checker as a function below this part and it is done.